# Переменное число параметров python

Tags: python, функции, переменные

Прохожу тему "Переменное число параметров python".

```
def total(a=5, *numbers, **phonebook):
    print('a', a)

    #проход по всем элементам кортежа
    for single_item in numbers:
        print('single_item', single_item)

    #проход по всем элементам словаря
    for first_part, second_part in phonebook.items():
        print(first_part, second_part)

print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, Jack=1123, John=2231, Inge=1560))
```

**Результат:**

> a 10
>
> single_item 1
>
> single_item 2
>
> single_item 3
>
> Inge 1560
>
> John 2231
>
> Jack 1123
>
> None

Откуда в выводе берется None? Аргументов 7, а выводится 8. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`total` возвращает (неявно) `None`, а эта строка делает вывод результата вызова `total`:

```
print(total(10,1,2,3,Jack=1123,John=2231,Inge=1560))
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял.